# Fast Way to Get Data from Website in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that utilizes the Wikipedia API. As far as I can tell, the simplest way to use the API is to access an HTTP page with the requested command, for instance, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Apple&prop=links&pllimit=max) finds all links on the "Apple" wikipedia article. I want to implement commands like these into my Java program so I created the following snippet to fetch the data from a HTTP page:

```
    URLConnection connection = null;    // Connection to the URL data
    InputStreamReader iSR = null;       // Stream of the URL data
    BufferedReader bR = null;           // Reader of URL data
    URL url = null;                     // URL based on the specified link

    // Open the connection to the URL web page
    url = new URL(link);
    connection = url.openConnection();

    // Initialize the Readers
    iSR = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
    bR = new BufferedReader(iSR);

    // Fetch all of the lines from the buffered reader and join them all
    // together into a single string.
    return bR.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

This works fine for fetching data, however, it is very slow. Each fetch takes around half a second, which is unacceptable for my program, especially since processing the whole downloaded file only takes around 1/1000th of a second. Is there any way that I can somehow quickly download these small files?

Comment: How long does it take to download the page in e.g. Google Chrome or Firefox, running on the same PC like the Java program?

Comment: Downloading multiple small files will almost always be slower than one large one.

Comment: Any way you can do this in threads?

Comment: @ammoQ It's hard to say. My internet is around 90mbps, so I guess I would say that it downloads instantly.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I guess I could but I haven't really ever used them before and so I would like to avoid them for now if possible.

Comment: @user3250889 Use the developer tools (F12 in your browser) for an accurate timing.

Comment: One file is generally faster for many reasons, such as only having one point of failure (HTTP requests that hang are the worst), and only needing to configure one set of resources, such as `BufferedReader`.

Comment: I did a couple of tests and its ~180ms. That's better than the 500ms in Java but still kind of bad for the purposes that I need. I think it would probably be best if I obtain a local copy of the data rather than download it everytime.

Comment: Your program wastes a few CPU cycles by reading the page line-by-line, then concatenating the lines; you should rather use a large buffer and `InputStream.read` to read all at once. Anyway, don't expect to get better than said 180ms. If that's too much, you have to look for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The *fastest* way, if you don't mind not having the most up-to-date information (of course you could devise a way to keep the data up to date), would be to get a [dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download) of the data.

This would allow you to create your own server that could return pre-formatted data, as well as returning multiple data items with a single request, making it a lot faster than parsing HTML from multiple requests.